# C - Having trouble with sprintf and printing strings

Tags: c, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    char buf[100];

char *word1 = 'Holy';

char *word2 = 'Moly';
sprintf(buf,"%s %s", word1, word2);
printf("%s\n", buf);

}
```

Hello I'm trying to use sprintf, however I can't seem to get this program to work, am I doing something wrong? It compiles, but when I run it it gives me segmentation fault ( core dumped) or it crashes.

Comment: Single quotes are for single character literals only.

Comment: I apologize for wasting your time guys.... I thought it was a double quote... I have a 4k monitor so some things are to small... I apologize!

Comment: Pay attention to compiler warning/error messages

Comment: @teppic: Single quotes are for character constants. Which can be single-character or multi-character. The OP's example shows examples of multi-character constants.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the double quotes for the `char*`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char buf[100];
    char *word1 = "Holy";
    char *word2 = "Moly";
    sprintf(buf,"%s %s", word1, word2);
    printf("%s",buf);
}
```

Edit: And don't forget to use gcc -Wall to show ALL the warnings to spot more easily these mistakes! :D

Comment: always compile with the option -Wall to see all the warnings

Comment: Actually you can also do it with printf, it worked for me but I always use puts instead. Just change the single quotes to double quotes.

Comment: Why on earth would you recommend `puts` over `printf`?

Comment: I don't really, it is just the way I've always done it. Can you tell me why is printf prefered over puts(fputs)?. Edit: After quickly looking something up, is it for the new line character?(then fputs should work) or is there something else?

Comment: It a flexibility/control issue. `puts` appends a `newline` to all output and it is limited in what it can display. `printf`, on the other hand, provides fine-grain control over the `format-string` allowing exact formatting in almost all cases. (**note** the compiler with substitute `puts` for `printf` in simple cases for you. Compile `printf ("\n")` to assembler and check. You will find `puts` in its place. )

Comment: Thanks! @DavidC.Rankin So, besides the newline character it just has less functionality concerning formatting?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Note that GCC will probably optimize `printf("%s\n", buffer)` into `puts(buffer)`.

Comment: @Darwin57721 - Yes, that's it. It's just not something you see suggested as the preferred output method. It is well worth the time to open `man printf` and spend the time required to understand what goes into forming a proper `format string`. **All** parts of `%[flags][width][.precision][length]specifier` It will serve you well with all the `scanf/printf` functions equally.

Comment: Will do! Thanks for the extensive info @DavidC.Rankin!

Answer (score 1):

Try fixing these lines :

```
char *word1 = 'Holy'; 
char *word2 = 'Moly';
```

to:

```
char *word1 = "Holy";
char *word2 = "Moly";
```

That is because single quotes are only used with a single character not a string value.
Always pay attention to compiler warnings especially when you are dealing with pointers. If the compiler warnings was not enabled try enabling them as  Darwin57721 explained.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Your answer is correct, but there are a couple of things you could do to improve it.  One would be to compress it; show the two faulty lines adjacent to each other and then show the two fixed lines.  The other would be to explain a bit about what was wrong with the old version and why the new version is correct.  A superlative answer would also discuss paying attention to compilation warnings, reporting any unresolved warnings when requesting help, and recommending options such as `-Wall` with GCC to identify problems more swiftly.

Comment: Sorry for that, I updated my answer. it is my first answer so thanks a lot for the feed back.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about — you're learning, as we all did once upon a time.